# Converting an FM square wave into an FM waveform that is sinusoidal

Tags: frequency, modulation

How could I convert a frequency modulated square wave, like from the timer 555 output, into a frequency modulated sine wave?

P.S. I added here the image of the circuit schematic for a more complete detail regarding the information.

[image: Circuit Schematic]

Comment: Filter it. Depending on the various frequency ratios (carrier, deviation, modulation rate) that will vary from straightforward to difficult. Tell us those frequencies, we'll be in a better position to help you.

Comment: So it's actually possible! I borrowed a Frequency Modulation Transmitter (using 555 astable multivibrator) from the browser and it generates the intended FM waveform... I just want to know how to convert the waveform into its sine wave equivalent.

Comment: As @Neil_UK says: *Tell us those frequencies, we'll be in a better position to help you*

Comment: The message signal is 1 kHz whilst I intend the carrier to be 96 MHz (at the FM Band).

Comment: You're talking about an FM signal, but you're showing a 555, most likely achieving PWM. So what is it: FM or PWM?

Comment: Which version of 555 are you using that runs at 96 MHz? 1 kHz mod rate won't cause a problem to a 96 MHz carrier. What's your intended frequency deviation?

Comment: The 555 circuit you show there will produce a (roughly) 10kHz carrier. I don't believe that there's any 555 variant capable of generating an output anywhere near 96MHz.

Comment: My bad it's 9.6 K, not 9.6 × 10^7 Hz.

Comment: Ok, that's more realistic for the circuit you have, but it's no longer anywhere near the standard FM radio band. So if you're hoping to receive your transmission on a radio you'll be out-of-luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a high-quality sine wave, that is a very difficult proposition. A very pure sine wave implies a very limited frequency range at any given time, and the FM part makes this very difficult to do simply. If you're good with about 1% THD, there is an old part, the 8038 or MAX083 which is intended as a cheap function generator. You can use circuits like this https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/2/21.html
but it may not do a great job while the frequency is changing. In the latter case you'd use the 555 to generate a signal at 8 times the desired output frequency.